# Left side weaker than the right side

Tags: health

I'm having this strange problem. My left side is much weaker than my right side. While my right leg is perfect, my left leg feels comparatively weaker, meaning that I don't feel like putting my left leg on the ground, and feel like having a constant weight being applied on it. Don't feel numbness of any sort. Similarly, while I can lift weights easily with my right hand, it becomes comparatively difficult to do it with my left hand. Any reason or solution to it?

Comment: When do you feel this in your leg? Always or only during workouts?

Comment: Mainly during going to sleep, waking up, or when sitting idle. During workouts I get a tired feeling in my left leg but not in the right, at least not as much as in the left one.

Comment: I'd lean towards possibly a nerve problem, which puts this in recommending you see a doctor territory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended, See a neurologist and an orthopedist. I face this issue with my legs because one is slightly shorter than the other. In your case, the imbalance may be full body.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go see a vascular specialist.  Peripheral Artery Disease can cause those symptoms; but, so can many other things.  Our facility performs free screenings for PAD.  Look and see if there is someplace you can get a free screening before seeking other medical help.  If for no other reason, than to rule out something like PAD.